# Java Regular Expression - Match for anything but specific string

Tags: java, regex

How would I write a Java regular expression that matches everything except the following string?

```
abc123DEF@domain.com
```

(?!abc123DEF@domain.com) doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide input string and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple change of your regex:

(?!abc123DEF@domain.com).*

it works.